# Trying to implement recurrent network with tf.scan()

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to implement a recurrent state tensor using `tf.scan`. The code I have at the moment is this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import math
import numpy as np

INPUTS = 10
HIDDEN_1 = 20
BATCH_SIZE = 3


def iterate_state(prev_state_tuple, input):
    with tf.name_scope('h1'):
        weights = tf.get_variable('W', shape=[INPUTS, HIDDEN_1], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(INPUTS))))
        biases = tf.get_variable('bias', shape=[HIDDEN_1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        matmuladd = tf.matmul(inputs, weights) + biases
        unpacked_state, unpacked_out = tf.split(0,2,prev_state_tuple)
        prev_state = unpacked_state
        state = 0.9* prev_state + 0.1*matmuladd
        output = tf.nn.relu(state)
        return tf.concat(0,[state, output])

def data_iter():
    while True:
        idxs = np.random.rand(BATCH_SIZE, INPUTS)
        yield idxs

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(BATCH_SIZE, INPUTS))
    with tf.variable_scope('states'):
        initial_state = tf.zeros([HIDDEN_1],
                                 name='initial_state')
        initial_out = tf.zeros([HIDDEN_1],
                                 name='initial_out')
        concat_tensor = tf.concat(0,[initial_state, initial_out])
        states, output = tf.scan(iterate_state, inputs,
                                     initializer=concat_tensor, name='states')

    sess = tf.Session()
    # Run the Op to initialize the variables.
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    iter_ = data_iter()
    for i in xrange(0, 2):
        print ("iteration: ",i)
        input_data = iter_.next()
        out,st = sess.run([output,states], feed_dict={ inputs: input_data})
```

However, I get this error when running this:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cycles_in_graphs_with_scan.py", line 37, in <module>
    initializer=concat_tensor, name='states')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 442, in __iter__
    raise TypeError("'Tensor' object is not iterable.")
TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.
(tensorflow)charlesq@Leviathan ~/projects/stuff $ python cycles_in_graphs_with_scan.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cycles_in_graphs_with_scan.py", line 37, in <module>
    initializer=concat_tensor, name='states')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 442, in __iter__
    raise TypeError("'Tensor' object is not iterable.")
TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.
```

I've already tried with `pack/unpack` and `concat/split` but I get this same error.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting an error because [`tf.scan()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/functional_ops.html#scan) returns a **single** `tf.Tensor`, so the line:

```
states, output = tf.scan(...)
```

...cannot destructure (unpack) the tensor returned from `tf.scan()` into two values (`states` and `outputs`). Effectively, the code is trying to treat the result of `tf.scan()` as a list of length 2, and assign the first element to `states` and the second element to `output`, but—unlike a Python list or tuple—`tf.Tensor` does not support this.

Instead you need to extract the values from the result of `tf.scan()` manually. For example, using [`tf.split()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#split):

```
scan_result = tf.scan(...)
# Assumes values are packed together along `split_dim`.
states, output = tf.split(split_dim, 2, scan_result)
```

Alternatively, you could use [`tf.slice()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#slice) or [`tf.unpack()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#unpack) to extract the relevant `states` and `output` values.